# jQuery: Modify appended object's CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$('#foo').css({color:'black'}).append('<div>bar</div>').css({color:'red'});
```

Given the above, the `css()` method is applied to `foo`, but how could you get it to apply to the div that wraps "bar"?

The only way I could think of to do this in the same execution line would be to create a jQuery div object inside of the `append(function(){ ... })` and apply the styling there.

---

***Note:** I'm trying to avoid inline styling (eg `.append('<div style="color:red;">bar</div>')`).*

---

***Update:** I'm actually applying css to foo as well; The example has been updated to reflect this*

Comment: Three virtually identical answers all at the same time... LOL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can flip the chain around so [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) runs on the appended element by using [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) instead, like this:

```
$('<div>bar</div>').appendTo('#foo').css({color:'red'});
//or:
$('<div>bar</div>').css({color:'red'}).appendTo('#foo');
//or:
$('<div />', { text:'bar', css: {color:'red'} }).appendTo('#foo');
```

Comment: The funny thing is I decided not to use `appendTo` because of the logical flow for the rest of the script, but this actually makes sense to use it here.  Cheers

Comment: I remember why I did now, because I'm also applying css to `foo`, I'll edit my example.

Comment: @vol7ron - You can also do `$('#foo').append($('<div />', { text:'bar', css: {color:'red'} }))` to keep chaining with `#foo` if you want...or `$('<div />', { text:'bar', css: {color:'red'} }).appendTo('#foo').parent().addClass("something");` or `$('<div>bar</div>').css({color:'red'}).appendTo('#foo').parent().addClass("something");`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('<div>bar</div>').css({color:'red'}).appendTo('#foo');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#foo').append($('<div>bar</div>').css({color:'red'}));
```

Comment: This is similar to what I was doing only I had `.append($(document.createElement('div')).css({...}))`

Answer (score 2):

or $something like

```
$('#foo').append($('<div />').text('bar').css({color:'red'}));
```

Comment: This is similar to what I was doing only I had `.append($(document.createElement('div')).css({...}))`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use appendTo() rather than append():

```
$('<div>bar</div>').css({color:'red'}).appendTo('#foo');
```

You can find a working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/YdzGZ/

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
$('#foo').append('<div>bar</div>').end().css({color:'red'});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you take a step back from the dynamic approach and create a rule or two in css?

```
#foo { color: black; }
#foo div,
#foo .orViaSomeClassName { color: red; }
```

No need to monkey about with injected inline styles that way.

And finally yet another approach to getting to the appended div:

```
$('#foo')
    .css('color', 'black') // css on #foo
    .append('<div>bar</div>') // appended to #foo
    .find('div')
        .css('color', 'red'); // css on divs inside #foo
```

Comment: I was going to post a comment about that.  CSS definitions/rules are not an option.  This has less to do with a need and more to do with a learning exercise.  Also the `find` could return multiple results, it is not referring to the newly created `div`.  I know you could use the `last` or `first` selector, but I tried to be careful about the example, not adding a class or id to the newly created object was on purpose.  I was trying to sway users to come up with unique efficient solutions according to the question, much like Josiah's example.